# Convert RGB + Opacity to RGB/HSL color

Tags: css, colors

The following link provides color data like "rgb #FFFFFF + opacity 70%".

For `react-native` I need the color in one of the following formats:

- hsl(x, y%, z%)
- rgb(x, y, z)

How do I convert the color above to this formats? (I think hsl -> rgb and back should be easy then)

The solution should not only work for #FFFFFF.

Answer (score 3):

To convert RGBA to RGB you need to provide the background color, which will be mixed in. Someone wrote a code snippet for that, I'm just pasting it here. I didn't program it myself.

https://gist.github.com/tqc/2564280

```
function RGBAtoRGB(r, g, b, a, r2,g2,b2){
    var r3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * r2) + (a * r))
    var g3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * g2) + (a * g))
    var b3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * b2) + (a * b))
    return "rgb("+r3+","+g3+","+b3+")";
    } 

let result = RGBAtoRGB(225,110,0,0.5,255,255,255);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't code transparency as RGB or HSL. What you need is the alpha component.
In that case it has to be RGBA or HSLA.

RGBA:

```
color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
```

HSLA:

```
color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.7);
```

You can try to reduce the opacity, but it will reduce the opacity of the whole element.

```
background: #fff;
opacity: 0.7
```

Comment: It souldn't be transparent, because there are elements over other elements where you shouldn't see the underlying elements.